# ElasticSearch 2.4.6 does not start at all without any error message Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.4

Trying to start elasticsearch 2.4.6 with `./elasticsearch` in the bin direcytory. It just closes and nothing happens. See the below screenshot

[image: ElasticSearch 2.4.6]

Stepping through the starter scripts, I can see that  it comes until `exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS $ES_JAVA_OPTS -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch start "$@"` line and then closes.

However, please note that elasticsearch 5.* does not have this problem and starts normally without error[image: ElasticSearch 5.*]

Can anyone tell me what could possibly be causing this? Or at least where can I find any error log. No error is logged in logs file of elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a kernel bug due to a fix for meltdown vulnerability. It is fixed by downgrading the kernel. (Or upgrading elasticsearch or the kernel as for now.)